# Specifying type of measure with lasso regression

Tags: r, measure, poisson, glmnet, lasso-regression

I'm trying to do variable selection with glmnet and lasso poisson regression.

It runs if I use:

```
model.lasso <- glmnet(X,ED.visits, family="poisson", alpha=1, nlambda=1000)
```

But I've been asked to use "deviance" as a measure. I get an error when I run:

```
model.lasso <- glmnet(X,ED.visits, type.measure=c("deviance"), family="poisson", alpha=1, nlambda=1000)
```

`type.measure` is the right specification according to: [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/3.0/topics/cv.glmnet).

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to put `c(…)` around single values, it’s the same as just writing `"deviance"` in your case. Apart from that, please post the error message you’re getting.

Comment: Yeah, I use ="deviance" and = c("deviance") interchangeably since my professor does the same. Sometimes we quickly add another measure. But thanks.

Comment: Hm. Honestly, that isn’t a good idea, I recommend not doing this: avoid clutter in code, it reduces readability and has a tendency of building up over time. There should be a zero-tolerance policy towards unnecessary, non-functional code fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument: type.measure, is not part of the glmnet function but the cv.glmnet function. You are calling to an argument that is not part of the above described function.

Comment: Yes! That was it.  I was using type.measure="deviance" for both my model.lassoCV and my model.lasso.  It should have only been used with my model.lassoCV . (cv.glmnet) call and not the other. Thanks.   In my defense, it certainly appeared to be showing red on the first call yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

For a poisson family regression, by default it is fitting using deviance (minimizing it). The purpose of cv.glmnet is to find the optimal lambda using cross-validation, but since you already specified it, the results from using cv.glmnet and glmnet are the same:

```
library(glmnet)
x = matrix(rnorm(10000),1000,10)
y = rpois(1000,10)
cv.lasso <- cv.glmnet(x,y, 
type.measure="deviance", family="poisson", 
alpha=1, nlambda=1000)

model.lasso <- glmnet(x,y, family="poisson", 
alpha=1, nlambda=1000)

> identical(cv.lasso$glmnet.fit$beta,model.lasso$beta)
[1] TRUE
```

Do you need to find the optimal lambda? If not just use glmnet without the type="measure" argument.

Comment: Yes, I used nfolds=10 with the cv.glmnet function. Then used coef(model.lasso, s=model.lassoCV$lambda.min) to get the coeficients for the best model. I will comment above with my mistake. I used type.measure="deviance" for both calls, and it should have just been the first (cv.lasso).

Comment: This statement was also very helpful: "by default it is fitting using deviance (minimizing it)."  Thanks.